# Java design pattern: same method on multiple classes

Tags: java, android

I'm creating an Android application. I need to override the `draw` method on a number of UI classes to create a custom appearance. These classes all subclass `View`. I'm wondering what the best way to do this is. I'd like to be able to reuse code as much as possible, so I'm looking for help in organizing things. As I see it right now, I have 2 options:

**Option 1 - Subclass Everything**

If I want to use `LinearLayout`, I create `CustomLinearLayout`. If I want to use `ImageView`, I create `CustomImageView`. On each of these custom classes, I override `draw` exactly the same way. This doesn't seem efficient because I'm repeating code and extending a number of classes which do almost nothing.

**Option 2 - Subclass a Super Class**

My original thought was to extend `View` and create `CustomView`, because it's already a superclass of all the classes I want to use. This, however, doesn't work because all the existing subclasses I want to use are still extending `View`, not `CustomView`.

Is there a better way to do this? Am I missing something?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve in the end?

Comment: I'm overriding draw on a number of subclasses. I'm then grabbing a bitmap of the view and modifying it to give the appearance of degraded quality. This "problem" is something I've come across a few times now, so I want to understand if there is a better way to organize my project.

Comment: @Roman C: Can you elaborate? Wouldn't I still have to create all the new classes and implement the same functionality that's happening in my overridden draw?

Comment: Have an interface and the commonalities across all will be put into an abstract class and you will have custom implementations of this.

Comment: @raydowe If you have different sets of classes then you should create different sets of interfaces for each set and implement it whatever you override em or not you must do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution would be to extract your draw logic into a separate class `DrawingCode`. This could contain a static method or you could even use instances of `DrawingCode` to customize your drawing code with other parameters. Of course you'll still have to overwrite the `draw()` method, but only write one line of code to call `DrawingCode.draw(param1, param2)`. This way you get to store your drawing code in one central place and don't repeat yourself.

Comment: Looks like this is the best solution. I still have to create subclasses for everything I want to draw differently, but at least all the heavy lifting is one in one place.

Comment: Please can you name the design pattern suggested in this answer ?